# Universal Turing Machine simulation with bounded time overhead

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

Is it possible to design a Universal Turing Machine in which the simulation time of a given Turing Machine $M$ is bounded by a factor of $\mathcal{O}(\log|\Gamma|+\log|Q|)$ of the original running-time of $M$, where $\Gamma$ and $Q$ are the tape alphabet and states of $M$ respectively?

If so, how can this be done?

Comment: That's a good question. What have you tried so far? What is the performance of the best simulation you could think of?

Comment: If we try to encode one character of input on UTM it takes log|T| bits. similarly for states also we can do this. then for each transition on original TM, UTM takes log|T|+log|Q| steps. Is my arguments are correct.

Comment: The UTM has to simultaneously read the "program" (the Turing machine it's simulating) and the "data" (the tape that the simulated Turing machine operates on). How do you handle that?

Comment: Does 
[Universal simulation of Turing machines](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2878/universal-simulation-of-turing-machines)
answer your question?

Comment: How do you look up the value of the transition function in time $o(|\Gamma|\cdot|Q|)$? At least I don't see how to encode said table in that *space* and TMs don't have random access. That may be a naive thought, but still.