# Limits on the time of computation for a UTM simulating a TM

Tags: turing-machines

According to [source](https://books.google.ca/books?id=nGvI7cOuOOQC&pg=PA9&dq=Arora%20and%20Barak,%20%202009,%20%20Theorem%201.9&lr=&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q=Arora%20and%20Barak%2C%20%202009%2C%20%20Theorem%201.9&f=false) page 20, theorem 1.9, it states that there is a universal Turing machine that can simulate any Turing machine with a time overhead of 
$O(\log n)$.

Can a universal Turing machine exists with less overhead? Can we prove that no such universal Turing machine exists?

If not, can we at least prove a lower bound on the overhead?

Comment: I believe it is an open question.

Comment: @Yuval What about if we restrict a UTM to simulating another UTM. Is it then still an open question?

Comment: This isn't really well-defined.

Comment: [related](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2878/universal-simulation-of-turing-machines)