# Is Turing machine is robust?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

Is Turing machine is robust ?
if it solved with one tape, can it solved with multi-tape?
I know that TM is robust but i can't understand why

Comment: This is classical material, which is described in textbooks.

Answer (score 3):

If you can solve it with one tape, you can solve it with multiple tapes by just ignoring all but the first tape.

The other direction is covered by [Universal simulation of Turing machines](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2878/755).